# Basic grep regex

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to use grep to find all files whose contents contain ".ple". I tried:

```
grep -ilr /.\.ple/ *
```

But it did not work.

Would someone be able to tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you mean by it did not work?

Try this:

```
grep -rlE '\.ple$'
```

The above should work.

Edit: To search all files whose contents contain ".ple" try this

```
grep -rl '\.ple'
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain what the downvote is for, so I can avoid making the same mistake in the future.

Comment: 1) your very first line is a question, not an answer. If you are unclear about a question, then you should post a comment on the question, not post an answer. 2) you're missing filename arg, which should at least be `*`.  3) regex itself is wrong. OP asked for files that **contain** ".ple", not files **who have lines ending in** ".ple". 4) pretty sure you don't need that `E` option; near as i can tell, it's not relevant

Comment: Dear Crayon Violet, 
Regarding your comment:
"1) your very first line is a question, not an answer."
I fail to see how this can be constructive in any way. While the other part of your comment may be useful, the general tone of your comment is unnecessarily demotivating. The fact that I'm a "newbie" should be obvious from the nature of my question, so could you tell me how I can downvote your comment? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there are many programming/script languages allow us to write regex between `/.../` (slashes). But with grep, you cannot do it, you should wrap your regex expression in quotes. I think that is the problem of your grep line. The correct one:

```
grep -ilr '.\.ple' *
```

with yours: `grep -ilr /.\.ple/ *` grep will look for lines like this:

```
foo/a.ple/bar
```

that is, the slash would be literal letter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and correct answer Kent. It seems I can only accept one answer. As the other one is shorter and fits my needs, I've accepted the other answer. Thanks again.